# Open in OneNote: We couldn't open that location. It might not exist or you might not have permission to open it

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-web-apps, onedrive

We are using SharePoint 2016. I have a sitecollection where I have some new created OneNote document in the document library "Shared Documents".

I shared this document to someone who dont have access to this sitecollection. He receives an email with an hyperlink to the OneNote document.

When he clicks on the hyperlink he has access to the OneNote document and see it in Office webapps. In Office webapps he can click on `Open in OneDrive` and receives the error:

> We couldn't open that location. It might not exist or you might not have permission to open it.
>
> Please contact the owner of `https://teams.mycompany.com/t/test12/Shared Documents/TestDocument/Test123.one#Test456` for more information.

Why is it working in office webapp but not in OneDrive which is part of the office suite on my machine?

**UPDATE**

I know why I receive this error.

When I create a new teamsite everything is working fine. When I activate the site collection scope feature `Publishing-Infrastructure SharePoint Server` I receive this error above.

Why is it not working with the publishing feature activated?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by my self. When you activate the feature "Publishing-Infrastructure SharePoint Server" it will automatically also enable the feature "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode". You need to disable the feature "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" and it works again.